# How to create custom properties to a Template Control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Template Control which has a StackPanel as it's root. What I want is a way to make something like this:

```
<Controls:MyControl Kind="SomeKind"/>
```

And based on SomeKind the StackPanel's background would change. There would be a limited number of "Kinds", the same way there is a limited number of HorizontalAlignments in a Button, for example.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I've searched in the internet a bit and it does seems like it involves Attached Properties, but I haven't found a clean, simple and easy-to-follow example for UWP. I've found some examples for WPF but they doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need attached properties since it's likely to be only associated within your custom control. What you need is a *dependency property* of an `enum` type.

Say if you have this `enum` -

```
public enum PanelBackgroundType
{
    Orange,
    Pink,
    Offwhite
}
```

Then your dependency property will look something like this -

```
public PanelBackgroundType PanelBackgroundType
{
    get { return (PanelBackgroundType)GetValue(PanelBackgroundTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PanelBackgroundTypeProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PanelBackgroundType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelBackgroundTypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PanelBackgroundType", typeof(PanelBackgroundType), typeof(MyControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(PanelBackgroundType.Offwhite, (s, e) =>
    {
        if ((PanelBackgroundType)e.NewValue != (PanelBackgroundType)e.OldValue)
        {
            // value really changed, invoke your changed logic here
            var control = (MyControl)s;

            switch ((PanelBackgroundType)(e.NewValue))
            {
                case PanelBackgroundType.Orange:
                    control.MyStackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                    break;
                case PanelBackgroundType.Pink:
                    control.MyStackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
                    break;
                case PanelBackgroundType.Offwhite:
                default:
                    control.MyStackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // else this was invoked because of boxing, do nothing
        }
    }));
```

Note that I have a check `(PanelBackgroundType)e.NewValue != (PanelBackgroundType)e.OldValue` inside the property changed callback to see if the value of the dp really has changed. This may seem redundant but according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties#property-metadata-for-a-custom-dependency-property), this is the best practise as -

> If the type of a DependencyProperty is an enumeration or a structure,
>   the callback may be invoked even if the internal values of the
>   structure or the enumeration value did not change. This is different
>   from a system primitive such as a string where it only is invoked if
>   the value changed. This is a side effect of box and unbox operations
>   on these values that is done internally. If you have a
>   PropertyChangedCallback method for a property where your value is an
>   enumeration or structure, you need to compare the OldValue and
>   NewValue by casting the values yourself and using the overloaded
>   comparison operators that are available to the now-cast values. Or, if
>   no such operator is available (which might be the case for a custom
>   structure), you may need to compare the individual values. You would
>   typically choose to do nothing if the result is that the values have
>   not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties

It will show you how to add custom dependency properties for an object that you'll be able to edit in the UI.

I'll give you a quick example of what you want event though I recommend you to take a look at Microsoft's docs

```
public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KindProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Kind", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnKindChanged)));

    public string Kind
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(KindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KindProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnKindChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Executed method when the KindProperty is changed
    }
}
```